in QueryDSL DTO Conversion, cannot fetch. cannot find query?
I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to convert results to a DTO in QueryDSL.
ERROR : Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.querydsl.jpa.JPASubQuery.toString()
public class CustomizedMemberCouponRepositoryImpl extends QuerydslRepositorySupport
    implements CustomizedMemberCouponRepository {

    public CustomizedMemberCouponRepositoryImpl() {
        super(MemberCoupon.class);
    }


    @Override
    public List<GetMemberCouponResponse> findGeneralCouponsByMemberId(Long memberId, boolean validOnly) {
        QMemberCoupon memberCoupon = QMemberCoupon.memberCoupon;
        QCoupon coupon = QCoupon.coupon;

        JPQLQuery<GetMemberCouponResponse> query = select(Projections.constructor(GetMemberCouponResponse.class,
                        memberCoupon.id,
                        coupon.code,
                        coupon.name,
                        coupon.discountAmount,
                        coupon.discountType,
                        coupon.maxDiscountAmount,
                        coupon.minPurchaseAmount,
                        coupon.startedAt,
                        coupon.expirationAt))
                .from(memberCoupon)
                .join(memberCoupon.coupon, coupon)
                .where(memberCoupon.memberId.eq(memberId)
                        .and(coupon.code.startsWith("G")));

        if (validOnly) {
            query.where(
                    coupon.startedAt.before(LocalDateTime.now()),
                    coupon.expirationAt.after(LocalDateTime.now()),
                    memberCoupon.status.eq(MemberCouponStatus.UNUSED)
            );
        }

        return query.fetch();
    }

It's my code.
@Builder
public record GetMemberCouponResponse(Long memberCouponId, String code, String name, long discountAmount,
                                      DiscountType discountType, long maxDiscountAmount, long minPurchaseAmount,
                                      LocalDateTime startedAt, LocalDateTime expirationAt) {
    public static GetMemberCouponResponse fromEntity(MemberCoupon memberCoupon) {
        return GetMemberCouponResponse.builder()
                .memberCouponId(memberCoupon.getId())
                .code(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getCode())
                .name(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getName())
                .discountAmount(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getDiscountAmount())
                .discountType(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getDiscountType())
                .maxDiscountAmount(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getMaxDiscountAmount())
                .minPurchaseAmount(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getMinPurchaseAmount())
                .startedAt(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getStartedAt())
                .expirationAt(memberCoupon.getCoupon().getExpirationAt())
                .build();
    }


}

Any idea how to fix this?
I have also tried removing @Builder from the DTO and using the generated Q class, but it didn't work. I suspect the error might be related to the DTO conversion process.
